# Forking example - Ethereum 101

Tags: forks

In the forking example on Ethereum 101 course on b9lab's website, could someone clarify why transaction 7 appears in ledger fork 1?

Thanks!

https://academy.b9lab.com/courses/B9lab/X16-0/2016/courseware/78cf6a6b90ac4b27b229e66fc23bd6f7/38a21e27851e40f8b7c9ce364ba0f19f/

Comment: Welcome to Ethereum Stack Exchange. Unfortunately, this link is only visible for registered users. Can you add more information to your question to allow non-b9lab students to help you with that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nodes that are part of the same network may be on different forks. However, they keep exchanging transactions and blocks, oblivious to which fork the others are on. So when a node receives a transaction, it only checks its validity within the context of its own fork. Of course, a given transaction may be valid on 2 different forks. As such the transaction may be added into 2 different blocks on 2 different forks.